# how to use regular expression to match the string included two backslash

Tags: python, regex

I have to write a regular expression refer to a string.I need to get the part between "$u" and the final "$",also I need match the part before "$u"
Now I wrote the regular expression as follow, but it can not work

```
a='=856  \\$uhttp://sfx-852cuh.hosted$'
#Two backslash may replace by other characters:a='=856  aa$uhttp://sfx-852cuh.hosted$'
result=re.search('=\w{3}\s{2}\S{2}\$u(.*)\$', a)
target_str=result.group(1)
```

Comment: Replace `\S{2}` with `\S` and retry. ``\\`` is actually 1 symbol. Also, why not use [`r'\$u([^$]+)'`](https://ideone.com/yNmbzK)?

Comment: Don't assignn to `str`. That's a built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\S{2}` with `\S{1,2}` if you expect 1 or 2 non-whitespace chars before `$u` and do not use a variable with `str` name:

```
import re
a='=856  \\$uhttp://sfx-852cuh.hosted$'
result=re.search(r'=\w{3}\s{2}\S{1,2}\$u(.*)\$', a)
expected_value = ''
if result:
    expected_value = result.group(1)
print(expected_value)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yNmbzK)

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: So, you can have 1 or 2 non-whitespace chars before `$u`, right? You need to indicate that in your question.